# Multiple Laravel Horizon(s) on same server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I am running two Laravel 5.8 apps (yasmin and stcc) on one server via Forge and I use `"laravel/horizon": "^3.2"` with both websites. I start and keep the queue workers up via Forge Daemons `php artisan horizon` command on both directories.

In both websites `.env` and `horizon.php` config files I set **unique queue names and prefixes** so the jobs dont mix, plus I changed **memory limit to 32MB** (so far I am only using jobs to send emails).

It works fine, only I have some questions because I see some differences and strange behavior.

**First question:** Why I dont see "CPU Threads" and "Memory" columns on stcc Horizon dashboard and in yasmin dashboard it doesnt show anything?

yasmin
[image: yasmin]

stcc
[image: stcc]

**Second question:** Why does the `htop` command shows that processes use 128MB of memory?

htop
[image: htop]

I restarted whole server and clear-cached both laravel configs with `php artisan optimize` command before running Horizon, yet these two things still bother me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These metrics were removed from Laravel Horizon in this PR: https://github.com/laravel/horizon/pull/616

The following explanation was provided:

> Since this PR was causing quite some bugs for others and also introduced a performance hit we've decided to revert it entirely. We also won't be re-considering a new PR anymore. We'd like to encourage you to use other tools to track and measure CPU/Memory consumption and just keep Horizon to its core features.

It was removed in `v3.2.3`. `v3.2.2` still had these metrics. The feature was really quite short-lived.